# Display Listview onClick button from Activity A to ActivityB

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick

I am a very Beginner to android development. I have a Main activity which contains a Button. Onclick of Button,it has to open a Simple Listview. Please Help me

---

//Main Layout       - This is my Main activity Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:background="#F0F2DF"
    tools:context="com.pureconcept.HomePage" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/image001" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:text="UserName"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#DE2F32" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#DE2F32" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:text="Sign in" 
        android:onClick="onclickSigin"/>

</RelativeLayout>
  -----------------------------------
```

//Welcome Layout       - This is my Welcome activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Menu_List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0F2DF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome Subbu!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Menu"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TwoLineListItem
        android:id="@+id/twoLineListItem2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
```

// Homepage. Java. Here i am inflating the Two Layouts on the Click on button.

```
public void onclickSigin(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View appearance = inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_layout,(android.view.ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.Menu_List));

            }


    }
```

// Welcome.java -- I am trying to Populate ListView . This should display on click of button from Homepage activity.

```
private void populateMenuList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] menuitems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuitems);
    ArrayAdapter<String> menuadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuitems);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Menu_List);
    lv.setAdapter(menuadapter);

}
}
```

I get the following error :
Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo. I am very new to android. Please explain

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView modeList = new ListView(this);
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Bright Mode", "Normal Mode" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
    modeList.setVisibility(View.VISISBLE);
  }
});
```

Something like this should work for you.

Comment: Ok,So whatever i wrote on Second activity java page,i should write it on main page?

Answer (score 0):

just add following line below `listview_object.setAdapter.array_adapter_object`

```
array_adapter_objectname.notifyDataSetChange();
```